# VSCode Problem: If `( * )` has no mutable arguments partially applied then the lambda can be removed

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#

The following line causes `F# Linter` to list the problem in the title (not an error, but suggestion) in `VSCode`, pointing to the `lambda`:

```
let product = [1;5;4;9;3] |> List.reduce (fun a b -> a * b)
```

Can this be simplified? I don't know of any other way to write this multiply function inline without the lambda. Also, I couldn't find this function in the `System.Math` class or an `F#` equivalent function.

Or is `F# Linter` wrong in this case?

Comment: Honestly bad linter suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduce` expects a function of 2 arguments and operator of multiplication `*` is a function of 2 arguments, that you can pass directly without wrapping it in a `fun`.

So lint suggests you to write it this way:

`let product = [1;5;4;9;3] |> List.reduce (*)`